# When and on whom do the infinity sign "tattoos" appear?

Tags: annihilation

On Lena's left forearm there are some scenes where a black marking that looks like a tattoo of an infinity symbol (a sideways 8) is visible. In other scenes it's clearly absent (such as when Lena takes a sample of her own blood in the village with the trees). In most movies I would call that a continuity error, but in Annihilation it's almost certainly both deliberate and significant. I also thought I saw a marking like that on Kane's forearm during the video with the knife (on the memory card left in the mess hall), though I could be remembering it wrong.

What are all the scenes in which we see infinity sign tattoos/markings on characters' arms, and on which characters?

Comment: I must say, these *infinity sign tattoos* were likely to be inspired by the ABC Drama TV Series, **Revenge**, where the main character, Emily (not including Victoria) had a special connection with *infinity times infinity* and had a tattoo of an infinity symbol on her wrist. If the TV Series was a country, then that symbol would be on its flag. Also, the movie, Annihilation, came out 5 days ago...

Comment: It's worth noting that the tattoo design is called a "infinity ouroboros"

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I thought it looked like ouroboros, but those are apparently circle-shaped in most cases so I decided not to use that terminology in the question.

Comment: "Pool Wall Guy" is the highlight of his career!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ok from memory, just watched the film and went back through it to find tattoo occurrences, the one good thing about it being released on netflix in this territory.

spoilers below:

1. On Lena's arm while being interviewed by Lomax (last chronologically)
2. On Anya's arm when she meets Lena and gives Lena a beer
3. Lena mention's a bruise on her arm in the canoe
4. you see the tattoo on the arm of the guy who's stomach is being cut open (not on Kane's) in the video
5. you see the tattoo on the same guy while on the pool wall
6. again on Anya's arm in the watch tower
7. a slight shape on Lena's arm as she searches for Sheppard's body
8. a more distinct infinity ouroboros bruise as Lena samples her own blood
9. a fully distinct tattoo on both Lena's arm and the doppelgänger's arm in the light house
10. more views on Lena's arm as she is being debriefed by Lomax

notes:

- Anya has the only occurrence shown of the tattoo outside the shimmer before the scientists enter
- it's not clear when pool wall guy get's cut up, anywhere in the stated twelve months is possible
- pool wall guy also seems to have some of Kane's shoulder tattoo

I will update as more are found

Answer (score 0):

The guy who was spread all over the wall in the pool also had one. I think it’s an infinity ouroboros, meaning that the changing will never end.

Comment: This is a good start, do you have any more examples that could tell us *when and on whom the tattoos appear*?